# REST URIs and operations on an object that can be commented on, tagged, rated, etc

Tags: web-services, rest

I'm doing research into a web API for my company, and it's starting to look like we might implement a RESTful one. I've read a couple of books about this now (O'Reilly's "RESTful web services" seeming the most useful) and have come up with the following set of URIs and operations for an object that can be commented on, tagged, and rated.

It doesn't really matter what the object is, as this scenario applies to many things on the net, but for the sake of argument lets say it's a movie.

Some of these seem to fit quite naturally, but others seem a bit forced (rating and tagging particularly) so does anybody have any suggestions about how these could be improved? I'll list them with the URI and then the supported verbs, and what I propose they would do.

```
/movies
```

GET = List movies

```
/movies/5
```

GET = Get movie 5

```
/movies/5/comments
```

GET = List comments on movie 5

POST = Create a new comment on movie 5

```
/movies/5/comments/8
```

GET = Get comment 8 on movie 5

POST = Reply to comment 8 on movie 5

PUT = Update comment 8 on movie 5

```
/movies/5/comments/8/flag
```

GET = Check whether the movies is flagged as inappropriate (404 if not)

PUT = Flag movie as inappropriate

```
/movies/5/rating
```

GET = Get the rating of the movie

POST = Add the user rating of the movie to the overall rating

*Edit: My intention is that the movie object would contain its rating as a property, so I wouldn't really expect the GET method to be used here. The URI really exists so that the rating can be an individual resource that can be updated using the POST verb. I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing it, but I can't think of a better one*

```
/movies/5/tags/tagname
```

GET = Check whether the movies is tagged with *tagname* (404 if not; but if it is tagged with the tag name should it return the actual tag resource by redirecting to something like `/tags/tagname`?)

PUT = Add tag *tagname* to the movie, creating the tag resource `/tags/tagname` if required

DELETE = Remove tag *tagname* from the movie, deleting the tag resource `tags/tagname` if nothing is tagged with it after this removal

---

Note that these wouldn't be the entire URIs, for example the URI to list the movies would support filtering, paging and sorting. For this I was planning on something like:

```
/movies/action;90s/rating,desc/20-40
```

Where:

action;90s is a semi-colon delimited set of filter criteria

rating,desc is the sort order and direction

20-40 is the range of item indices to get

Any comments about this API scheme too?

---

**Edit #1**

This post is getting quite long now! After reading some of the answers and comments, this is the changes from above I'm planning on making:

Tags will be handled as a group rather than individually, so they will be at:

```
/movies/5/tags
```

GET = List tags

POST = Union of specified tags and existing tags

PUT = Replace any current tags with specified tags

DELETE = Delete all tags

I'm still really not sure how to handle flagging a comment though. One option is that instead of POSTing to a comment replying to it, a comment object will include its parent so it can be POSTed to the general URI, i.e.

```
/movie/5/comment
```

POST = Create a new comment (which may be a reply to a comment)

I could then use the POST to a comment to flag it. But this still doesn't feel quite right.

```
/movie/5/comment/8
```

POST = Flag comment

Comment: This basically looks good to me - is there an actual question other than opinion canvasing?

Comment: The question is really whether there a better way to model this, particularly tagging and commenting which I'm a bit unsure about. I haven't implemented a RESTful service before so want to get it right, and get opinions from others who have done it before.

Comment: When you post to a Comment url like /movie/5/comment/8/ your post body would have all properties of the comment. [form] {id:8,text:"this movie is...blah blah", flag:true} [form]. On the server you just make the update on the fields that changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of what you have looks good. There were just a couple of strange things I saw. When I put my URLs together, I try to follow these four principles.

### Peel the onion

If you make the R in REST really be a resource then the resource URL should be able to be peeled back and still be meaningful. If it doesn't make sense you should rethink how to organize the resource. So in the case below, each makes sense. I am either looking at a specific item, or a collection of items.

```
/movies/horror/10/
/movies/horror/
/movies/
```

The following seems funny to me because `flag` isn't a resource, it's a property of the `movie`.

```
/movies/5/comments/8/flag -> Funny
/movies/5/comments/8/     -> Gives me all properties of comment including flag
```

### Define the View

The last peice of the URL describes how to show the resource. The URL `/movies/horror/`  tells me I will have a collection of movies refined by horror. But there might be different ways I want to display that collection.

```
/movies/horror/simple
/movies/horror/expanded
```

The simple view might just be the title and an image. The expanded view would give a lot more information like description, synopsis, and ratings.

### Helpers

After the resource has been limited and the proper view figured out, query string parameters are used to help the UI with the little stuff. The most common query string parameters I use are

```
p => Page
n => number of items to display
sortby => field to sort by
asc => sort ascending
```

So I could end up with a URL like

```
/movies/horror/default?p=12&n=50&sortby=name
```

This will give me the list of `movies` limited to horror movies with the default view; starting on page 12 with 50 movies per page where the movies are sorted by name.

### Actions

The last thing needed are your action on the resource. The action are either collection based or item based.

```
/movies/horror/
GET -> Get resources as a list
POST -> Create, Update

/movies/horror/10/
GET -> Get resource as item
POST -> Update
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Pretty much what i've been saying in all the comments but better organized and well put. I dont agree on the view though, imo a resource should be something you can apply all 4 verbs too. The view is just there for the sake of GET ...

Comment: [continued] .. whilst in practice it's just a filter which we both agree on should be in url variables :)

Comment: This is not REST. It is just RPC. You cannot define URIs as part of a RESTful API.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the way I see it some of the information you return now as objects could simply be added to the metadata of its parent object.

For instance, rating could be part of the response of /movies/5

```
<movie>
   <title>..</title>
   ..
   <rating url="movies/ratings/4">4</rating>
   <tags>
      <tag url="movies/tags/creative">creative</tag>
      ...
```

Removing a tag simply means posting the above response without that tag.

Also queries should go in URL variables, I believe:
`/movies/?startsWith=Forrest%20G&orderBy=DateAdded`

Comment: My intention was to include the rating & tags in the movie object, but if I stick to a RESTful architecture then these things need their own URLs to be able to create/update/delete them. So I wouldn't expect the rating GET to be used, really just the POST, I just put it in for completeness.

Comment: Question is however if you add a movie wouldnt you preffer posting 1 dataset one time over doing dozens of HTTP Requests ? In the above example tags are still a resource you can post too by the way ;).

Comment: That's an interesting point actually. In my scenarios the movie object or equivalent will be read-only (only GET supported) so the tags couldn't be posted as part of it, but in if the object did support POST then I think that's a pretty good idea.

Comment: Although... I could treat the collection of tags associated with the asset as a single resource, and do GET/POST/PUT/DELETE actions on the group as a whole. That seems cleaner than what I was planning... cheers!

Comment: It seems delicious has gone the same route. http://www.peej.co.uk/articles/restfully-delicious.html
bookmarks have tags but theres no /bookmarks/x/tags resource only a /tags/tag resource. Not saying this is definitive though i think neither implementation is wrong.

Comment: Would it be reasonable to implement POST on /movie/n with the proviso that only <rating> and <tags> would be used? That would clear up the issue with the /movie/n/rating URI too.

Comment: Must be my dutch tongue kicking in but do you mean no <title> <description> metadata in the POST ?

Comment: Yeah that was what I meant; the POST would just have the user's rating and/or the updated tags... but it just feels wrong to me really...

Comment: Well you can, most implementations i've seen allow you to drop properties you dont want to act on. for POST i can image <title><description><genre> being mandatory. But in a put you could leave them out of the body to leave them unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the edit. Queries should be defined by querystrings as per Martijn Laarman's post. i.e.:

```
/movies?genre=action&timeframe=90s&lbound=20&ubound=40&order=desc
```

Comment: I don't agree with that - it murders SEO and makes URIs less human readable. Also it forces a dependency on what you name your querystring vars.

Comment: This is one I'm really not sure about... that API is technically more a browse than a search (i.e. movies filed under action and 90s) and the books I've read seem to favour URI segments for those rather than query strings. Maybe a hybrid like /movies/action;90s?sort=rating,desc&range=20-40 ...?

Comment: REST is about using the HTTP protocol to your benefit url variables were implemented to filter a resource thats there purpose. Beats hacking up your own filtering in the URI.

Comment: Greg your right though that this is still very much up for debate and alot of different implementations have sprung from that debate. Url vars is mostly my own preference since i think sementically it just makes more sense.

Comment: @Martijn - It does make more sense to let the framework do the parsing etc. than to do it myself... so I think I'm with you guys on this one. Query parameters it is.

Comment: glad to hear it :) as Martijn again beat me to saying, query params were exactly intended for this

Comment: @Martijn, REST has nothing to do with HTTP.

Comment: @Wahnfrieden - It has everything to do with HTTP. The whole concept is centred on utilising HTTP GET/POST/PUT/DELETE for their built-in semantic value.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of ROA (I'm only on chapter five of RESTful Web Services) it looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is an awesome initial draft for a spec of a REST API. The next step would to specify expected return codes (like you did with "404 No Tag Available"), acceptable Content-Types, and available content-types (e.g., HTML, JSON). Doing that should expose any additional chinks you'll need to hammer out.

Answer (score 0):

@Nelson LaQuet:

Using the HTTP methods as they are actually defined gives you the safety of knowing that executing a GET on anything on a web site or service won't eat your data or otherwise mangle it.  As an example (pointed out in [**RESTful Web Services**](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529260/)) Google's Web Accelerator expects this behaviour -- as stated in the [FAQ](http://webaccelerator.google.com/webmasterhelp.html#prefetch3) -- and presumably other services do too.

Also it gets you [idempotency](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529260/) for free.  That is doing a GET, DELETE, HEAD or PUT on a resource more than once is the same as doing it only once.  Thus if your request fails then all you have to do is run it again.

Answer (score -2):

This is not REST.

> A REST API must not define fixed resource names or hierarchies (an obvious coupling of client and server). Servers must have the freedom to control their own namespace. Instead, allow servers to instruct clients on how to construct appropriate URIs, such as is done in HTML forms and URI templates, by defining those instructions within media types and link relations. [Failure here implies that clients are assuming a resource structure due to out-of band information, such as a domain-specific standard, which is the data-oriented equivalent to RPC's functional coupling].

http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven

Comment: I didn't say anything about the representation or how links would be communicated to a client. So I really don't see how this applies.

Comment: Just as long as you don't specify these URIs out-of-band. It looked like this was an API you were assembling, not just a nice human readable naming convention.